# How can I make jQuery.parseXML work in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, xml-parsing, activex

I am trying to use jQuery parseXml in node.js

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0"...
```

But the problem is **not** in the XML

The problem is in node-jquery.js:

```
parseXML: function( data ) {
        if ( typeof data !== "string" || !data ) {
            return null;
        }
        var xml, tmp;
        try {
            if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
                tmp = new DOMParser();
                xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
            } else { // IE
                xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
                xml.async = "false";
                xml.loadXML( data );
            }
        } catch( e ) {
            xml = undefined;
        }
        if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
            jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
        }
        return xml;
    },
```

To put it simply, in node.js, there is no **DOMParser**, and there is no **ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" )**

Since I am working in windows, I would expect ActiveXObject to work, but no, it does not, the actual error swallowed by jQuery is not an invalid XML it is that ActiveXObject is not defined:

```
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:
```

Any workarounds for this? How can I make jQuery.parseXML work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had great success using [xmldom](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom).  Take a look.  It seems to parse an xml just like you would expect `$.parseXML` to.  I was also having problems with the jquery parser and switched to this one after trying a bunch out.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to continue to use `jQuery.parseXML` without having to make any changes to your code (like if you want to be able to run the same javascript both client-side and in Node.js), it is easy to set that up. The [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmldom) module mentioned in [M. Laing’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697324/333625) exposes a `DOMParser` constructor that jQuery can use the same way it uses [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) in the browser. Here’s how to do so:

First, install xmldom:

```bsh
npm install xmldom --save
```

Assuming you already have jQuery 2.1.x or greater working in Node.js (for instructions on setting that up, see the README in [this repository](https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery)), you can now just require xmldom and expose its `DOMParser` constructor as a global:

```js
global.DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
```

jQuery will now be able to successfully `parseXML`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be something that would have to be implemented into the core of nodejs. I would suggest using a module designed to parse XML.

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Do you need jQuery.parseXML to work, like are you trying to write code to cross into the browser and run on the server?

You could probably expose [node-xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) in the browser with [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

There is also [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) which seems to be more XML like than node-xml2js.