# jQuery escaping <style> content

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm using jquery as an xml parser (big mistake). However, I have too much invested to switch now. I'm having issues with jQuery automatically escaping the `<style>` tag's content.

```
var a = $("<style><foo>content</foo></style>"),
    b = $("<bar><foo>content</foo></bar>");

b.find('foo').length // => 1
a.find('foo').length // => 0

b.html() // => '<foo>content</foo>'
a.html() // => 'foo>content</foo>'
         //     ^--- missing '<'

b.text() // 'test'
a.text() // 'foo>content</foo>'
```

Is there a way to prevent jQuery from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
var xml = jQuery.parseXML("<style><foo>content</foo></style>");
var a = $(xml);
```

in order to prevent jQuery from treating the `style` tag differently.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/FABmh/

Comment: ah. I'm using jquery on node and `parseXML` was throwing an exception when feeding it XML fragments. Same code works in the browser though. thanks!

Comment: @iliacholy Sorry for the double post, but what exception were you getting?

Comment: this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696853/how-can-i-make-jquery-parsexml-work-in-node-js and I'm not using any frameworks.

Comment: @iliacholy Ah yes, of course. Are you using any modules that can parse xml? You could try including something like [this module](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

Comment: no, but it wouldn't be hard to find one. I just wanted to use jquery because of the portability.